# Join two collections in MongoDB by merging properties from one into the other

Tags: mongodb

I need help joining two collections in MongoDB.

I have two collections: Cards and Decks. I need to join them so that I have the properties of the cards document inside the decks document. Below are two examples in JSON format of each collection:

1. Decks

Example:

```json
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "608edd53a8220000b2000882"
    },
    "name": "Izzet Phoenix",
    "cards": {
        "mainboard": [
            {
                "qty": "4",
                "name": "Arclight Phoenix",
                "id": "787de9ce-02c5-4a17-a88b-d38e83dbeb0b"
            },
            ... a bunch of other cards in the same format (qty, name, id)
        ],
        "sideboard": [
            {
                "qty": "2",
                "name": "Abrade",
                "id": "84319dfb-eaf7-4b98-8c4f-30f5e779591b"
            },
            ... a bunch of other cards in the same format (qty, name, id)
        ]
    },
    ... a bunch of other properties of the deck
}
```

2. Cards

Example:

```json
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "608b60d6a40a0000c9017853"
    },
    "name": "Abrade",
    "id": "84319dfb-eaf7-4b98-8c4f-30f5e779591b",
    ... a bunch of other properties of the card
}
```

Note that the decks collection uses the "id" field of cards as a reference, and not the "_id" field.

This is the desired output I'm looking for:

```json
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "608edd53a8220000b2000882"
    },
    "name": "Izzet Phoenix",
    "cards": {
        "mainboard": [
            {
                "qty": "4",
                "name": "Arclight Phoenix",
                "id": "787de9ce-02c5-4a17-a88b-d38e83dbeb0b",
                ... add properties of the card Arclight Phoenix, with id = 787de9ce-02c5-4a17-a88b-d38e83dbeb0b
            },
            ... a bunch of other cards
        ],
        "sideboard": [
            {
                "qty": "2",
                "name": "Abrade",
                "id": "84319dfb-eaf7-4b98-8c4f-30f5e779591b",
                ... add properties of the card Abrade, with id 84319dfb-eaf7-4b98-8c4f-30f5e779591b
            },
            ... a bunch of other cards
        ]
    },
    ... a bunch of other properties of the deck
}
```

I've tried looking into how to solve this, and I found that MongoDB has a $lookup stage, but I have no familiarity with the pipeline and stages concept, which ended up holding me back.

All help is appreciated.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out using a mix of $unwind, $lookup, $addFields, $group, and $project.

Final pipeline:

```js
db.getCollection("decks").aggregate(
    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $match: {
                "_id": ObjectId("608edd53a8220000b2000882")
            }
        },
        // Stage 2
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: "$cards.mainboard"
            }
        },
        // Stage 3
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "cards",
                localField: "cards.mainboard.id",
                foreignField: "id",
                as: "cards.mainboard.card"
            }
        },
        // Stage 4
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: "$cards.mainboard.card"
            }
        },
        // Stage 5
        {
            $addFields: {
                "cards.mainboard": {
                    "$mergeObjects": ["$cards.mainboard.card", "$cards.mainboard"]
                }
            }
        },
        // Stage 6
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$_id",
                "name": { "$first": "$name" },
                "cards": { "$first": "$cards" },
                "mainboardCards": { "$push": "$cards.mainboard" },
            }
        },
        // Stage 7
        {
            $project: {
                "mainboardCards.card": 0
            }
        },
        // Stage 8
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: "$cards.sideboard"
            }
        },
        // Stage 9
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "cards",
                localField: "cards.sideboard.id",
                foreignField: "id",
                as: "cards.sideboard.card"
            }
        },
        // Stage 10
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: "$cards.sideboard.card"
            }
        },
        // Stage 11
        {
            $addFields: {
                "cards.sideboard": {
                    "$mergeObjects": ["$cards.sideboard.card", "$cards.sideboard"]
                }
            }
        },
        // Stage 12
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$_id",
                "name": { "$first": "$name" },
                "mainboardCards": { "$first": "$mainboardCards" },
                "sideboardCards": { "$push": "$cards.sideboard" },
            }
        },
        // Stage 13
        {
            $project: {
                "sideboardCards.card": 0
            }
        },
    ],
);
```